# From Black Friday to Cyber Monday!

Tags: etymology, north-american-english, phrase-origin

Sources available [on line](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&ei=HOwHXP7_KKHmsAeY1KOIDw&q=cyber%20monday%20origin&oq=cyber%20monday%20origin&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0j0i22i30l4.3382.8275..8554...0.0..0.198.2486.0j15......0....1.........41j0i71j0i67.nDzJO7DOAiI&pccc=1) say that the expression “Cyber Monday” is just a few years old, dating its coinage to 2005:

> ***The term "Cyber Monday" was dreamt up in 2005 by a marketing team at Shop.org, a division of the National Retail Federation***. The idea was to provide online retailers with a catchy hook to match the brick-and-mortar shopping frenzy fueled by mention of Black Friday savings.

Searching online, it appears that the expression was used a few years earlier for philanthropic reasons, but on the same idea of an online transaction.

From ***[The e-way to philanthropy](https://books.google.it/books?id=agVHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cyber%20monday%22&dq=%22cyber%20monday%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCnrqS_4jfAhUSy6QKHRLtDw4Q6AEIJTAA)***, “how nonprofits can use information technology”:

> *Sheng-shu Jack Shen, ‎City University of New York. Center for the Study of Philanthropy - 2001-*

> - On October 4, 1999 Public Radio station WAMU ([www.wamu.org](http://www.wamu.org)) in Washington, DC suspended its normal on-air pledge drive for one day, ***called " Cyber-Monday."*** On that day 3,489 pledges totaling $227,000 were received through the ...

The above usage is probably just an example of how the expression may have been used before it was closely related and popularized by the Black Friday sales in 2005.

Is there more evidence of usage of “Cyber Monday” before 2005? and when was the expression actually first used?

Comment: Book link: https://www.gc.cuny.edu/CUNY_GC/media/CUNY-Graduate-Center/PDF/Centers/Center%20on%20Philanthropy%20and%20Civil%20Society/E-way.pdf

Comment: [“online” is one word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/online), why did you undo the spelling correction?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - https://www.google.it/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/on-line

Comment: Alternative spelling....OK.